# dataTables - No data available

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I've just started using dataTables for a web application, 
and I'm trying to populate a table from a json request.

The web page receives the json (I've checked in the sources on chrome debugging), but the table says 'No data available in table'.

Here is the json that is returned from the url part of the js

`{"Data":[{"username":"Testing","totalSteps":1000000,"gender":"Male"},{"username":"test","totalSteps":0,"gender":"Female"},{"username":"Testingggg","totalSteps":0,"gender":"Female"}]}`

which is in a `UserController`, from the method `GetAllUsers`

here is the html:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users - PDC";
}

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Users</h1>

    <table id="AllUsers" class="display" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>username</th>
                <th>totalSteps</th>
                <th>gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("getAllUsers", "User")',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                $('#AllUsers').DataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [

                        { "data": "username" },
                        { "data": "totalSteps" },
                        { "data": "gender" },
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Why isn't my json being parsed into the table?**

Comment: I think your response object should have this array

[{"username":"Testing","totalSteps":1000000,"gender":"Male"},{"username":"test","totalSteps":0,"gender":"Female"},{"username":"Testingggg","totalSteps":0,"gender":"Female"}]

not data as key.

Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rp0zw8rm/202/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use dataTables built-in AJAX? The above seems a little bit backwards. Your main problem is that the JSON array is named `Data` (capital D). dataTables expects `data`. You can change that through the `dataSrc` attribute :

```
$('#AllUsers').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: '@Url.Action("getAllUsers", "User")',
    dataSrc: 'Data'
  },
  columns: [
    { "data": "username" },
    { "data": "totalSteps" },
    { "data": "gender" }
  ]
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/952/**

Answer (score 1):

I think your response object should have this array only:

```
[
{"username":"Testing","totalSteps":1000000,"gender":"Male"}‌​,
{"username":"test",‌​"totalSteps":0,"gend‌​er":"Female"},
{"user‌​name":"Testingggg","‌​totalSteps":0,"gende‌​r":"Female"}
]
```

not data as key.

Please check this link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rp0zw8rm/202/

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Would you know how to get rid of the data key?
I'm making it through a json encoder passed from a controller.
I'll add more information once I'm back at my normal computer